# Event firing two times

Tags: vb.net, outlook-2010

i am Handling Event in vb.net

```
 AddHandler ButtonOne.Click, AddressOf ButtonClick

 Private Sub ButtonClick(ByVal ctrl As Office.CommandBarButton, ByRef Cancel As Boolean)
    //do stuff
 End sub
```

But my event calling twice.when i click onces on button and in another method also
i am handling same event

```
   Private Sub AddToolbar()
   // do something
     AddHandler firstButton.Click, AddressOf ButtonClick
   End
```

How to resovle this issue ?
plz help me

Comment: You just called AddHandler for the same button's Click event twice.  Delete one of them.

Comment: ButtonOne.Click and firstButton.Click are two different buttons

Comment: That's not what your complaint suggests.  "One" and "first" are suspiciously similar of course.  Picking good identifier names and avoiding storing a reference to an object in multiple variables are good ways to stay out of trouble.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Hans pointed out.... you are calling the button click twice... Also see below

```
AddHandler ButtonOne.Click, AddressOf ButtonClick 'You dont really need this if you add a handler to the sub see below...

 Private Sub ButtonClick(ByVal ctrl As Office.CommandBarButton, ByRef Cancel As Boolean) Handles ButtonOne.Click
    //do stuff
 End sub
```

Comment: Thanku so much save my lot of time